# Adding monthly subscription payment to chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, subscription, payment-processing

I'm approaching completion of my chrome extension and need to explore monthly subscription options. What is the best approach to doing this?

Comment: Take a look here [Monetizing Your Chrome Web Store Item](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/money)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the top-voted answer on this mentions Chrome Web Store Payments which was [shut down by Google on February 1, 2021](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/cws-payments-deprecation/).

The only other thing I know like Chrome Web Store payments to monetize your extension is [ExtensionPay](https://extensionpay.com). It's open source and works on all browsers, not just Chrome, which is nice.

Otherwise, you'll need to build an authentication system and sync it with your extension. Then you'll need to use a way of taking payments like Stripe or Paddle or Paypal or something and sync that with your user's extension.

Answer (score 4):

As @Deliaz stated, Chrome Web Store Payments supports both [monthly and yearly subscription](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/money#subscription) models. As with one-time Chrome Web Store payments, you have the option of providing a free trial.

For details about app payment options, you may check the [Charging for your app](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/overview#charging) documentation in the Overview.

Comment: Hi @abielita I'm going to integrate an extension with License API and it will have monthly fee. As I understand so far I will need to make verify the license call and check createdTime value, and if it greater than 1 month I will need to show link to web store. And after if user will pay subscription in next call createdTime will be changed to current date, am I right? I've searched the answer in documentation but so far could not find any info about it..

Comment: @Daniyar Have you found an answer to this? There doesn't seem to be any documentation?

Comment: Note that [Chrome web store payments is deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/cws-payments-deprecation). To plan ahead, go with a third-party solution.